# how to invalidate a users session

Tags: java, security, session, iframe, cookies

I work on an enterprise weblogic portal environment. Lets say the portal is on a.whereiwork.com and has many wsrp portlets as well as several iframed portlets that point to pages in another subdomain, b.whereiwork.com (legacy app we also own the codebase for). We have a current issue where users log out of the portal but when they log back in their session on b.whereiwork.com is persisted and we have some issues getting the JSESSION ID cleared on that subdomain.

This represents a major security issue as the next person to login on that computer might not be the same user (for instance someone logs in then out and his wife logs in and sees data from his session).

One thing we thought to try is add an iframe to the subdomain on the logout page which invalidates the session on the subdomain. Security is a little different on the other subdomain an its more complicated than I can really go into here. Take my word for it - it wont work.

The best idea we currently have is to add a top level servlet filter on b.whereiwork.com that checks to see if the security cookie has changed and then call session.invalidate(). This way if the user logs out we can leave their session as is unless they try to log back in. We can detect that it is a different login because the login is tracked in a separate cookie.

So my question is. Is there any issue calling session.invalidate() in a top level filter. Assume that other filters in the filter chain will need to create objects in the session. Im guessing after calling invalidate on the session that the page would return a different JSESSIONID?

Any other suggestions that might be cleaner would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ive decided to use jsonp to send a crossdomain message to the other domain to clear the session. Seems to be working.

Comment: How would you handle issues like session timeout on the main domain or restarting of the main domain server.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be to have the same security token across different servers. But as you said that is not possible. The next solution can be to use HTTPSessionListener to clear the session when the user logs out of main domain or when the session times out. That will ensure that the sessions across domains are in sync.